# Is there a way to get Internet Explorer not to wait until an AJAX request completes before following a link?

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer

I have a html page that displays some basic account information and begins a long-ish running jQuery AJAX request to retrieve more detailed data.  While the Ajax request is in progress it is possible for the user to click a button that has an `onclick` event to navigate to a new page using `location.assign`.

Unfortunately if the button is clicked before the ajax request is complete nothing will happen until the ajax request completes.  This is a live server issue.  I want the user to be able to immediately navigate away.  FF and Chrome appear to behave better but since this is a corporate intranet application they are not really an option.

The following code is similar to the page in question:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    $(function () {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/long-running-partial-html-ajax-endpoint',
            success: function (result) {
                $('#detail').html(result); });
            },
            error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#detail').html('Failed to load additional information:<br />' + textStatus + '<br />' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
//-->
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Account Information</h2>
        <div>Some basic details here</div>
        <div><button onclick="location.assign(&quot;/somewhere-else&quot;)" type="button">Go somewhere else now</button></div>
        <div id="detail">
            <img src="/ajax-loading-animation.gif" alt="Loading ..." />
            Loading ...
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Things I've tried in the debugger (not on live) already:

- using a plain `anchor` rather than a scripted button
- using `xhr.abort()` before the `location.assign`
- put `alert`s around the `location.assign` to reassure myself that the code is executing when expected

Observation:

- IE stops animating the gif as soon as the button is clicked.
- FF/Chrome must automatically abort the ajax request as the jQuery ajax `error` event is fired

Has anyone come across this issue before?  Have you a resolution that will make the navigation more responsive?

Comment: Have you tried an anchor with a href (as opposed to `location.assign`)?

Comment: Thanks for your interest Pekka.  A plain anchor was the first thing I tried as noted in my original post.

Comment: I've now tried the xhr.abort() in live with no effect other than the returned HTML does not get rendered: i.e the success function does not execute which is a small win I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up executing the long running task in a separate thread on the server.  The ajax call then just repeatedly calls in to check if a response is ready yet.  That way each ajax request is very short.

My solution is fine for a intranet application but would probably need to be made more robust for a Internet application.

So the html becomes:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    var detailRequest = null;

    function StartDetailRequest() {
        detailRequest = jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '<%= Url.Action("EnquiryDetail", "Account", new { requestGuid = ViewData["detailRequestGuid"] }) %>',
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.length == 0) {
                    setTimeout("StartDetailRequest()", 500);
                }
                else {
                    $('#detail').html(result);
                    $("table tbody").each(function () { $("tr:odd", this).addClass("odd"); });
                }
            },
            error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#detail').html('Failed to load additional information:<br />' + textStatus + '<br />' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }

    $(function () {
        setTimeout("StartDetailRequest()", 500);
    });
//-->
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Account Information</h2>
        <div>Some basic details here</div>
        <div><button onclick="location.assign(&quot;/somewhere-else&quot;)" type="button">Go somewhere else now</button></div>
        <div id="detail">
            <img src="/ajax-loading-animation.gif" alt="Loading ..." />
            Loading ...
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

On the server side I do something like (ASP.NET MVC 2 with pseudo code):

```
private Dictionary<Guid, DetailRequestObject> detailRequestList = new Dictionary<Guid, DetailRequestObject>();

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
  var model = GetTheBasicDetails(id);
  var request = CreateDetailRequestObject(id);

  CheckForTimedOutDetailRequests();

  detailRequestList.Add(request.Guid, request);

  ViewData["detailRequestGuid"] = request.Guid;

  return View(model);
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult EnquiryDetail(Guid requestGuid)
{
  DetailRequestObject detailRequest = detailRequestList[requestGuid];

  if (detailRequest == null)
  {
    throw new TimeoutException("Timed out retrieving details");
  }
  else if (!detailRequest.IsComplete)
  {
    return Content("");
  }
  else
  {
    var details = detailRequest.Response();

    return PartialView(details);
  }
}
```

The `DetailRequestObject` class encapsulates the creation of a separate thread using the async model of your choice, sets a flag when complete and collects the response data.

I also have a method `CheckForTimedOutDetailRequests` that collects requests that have timed out for retrieving so that any that have been 'aborted' can be cleared up.

I think I would prefer to have the long running requests run in a separate Windows Service that would do it's own clean-up, request throttling and such but the above works so...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to call the `ajax` method after the page is loaded

```
  <body onload="myFunctionThatCallsAjax()">
```

There are some browser behavior differences when you embed Javascript in the HTML code. Using `onload` will ensure this is not an issue.

Comment: Thanks for your interest ring0. I tried this out but it made no difference.  I am using the jQuery document ready function (`$(function() {});`) to start the ajax request anyway which I believe would achieve the same effect.